# How to modify objects using an iterator? using <list>

Tags: c++, list, iterator

So here's an example. The star's `mLocation` and `mSpeed` are a `Vector3` custom type.

I'v tried:

```
Star &star = *iStar;
Star star = *iStar;
```

Using `iStar->` directly doesn't work with my operators, not sure why.
So whats the proper way to do that?

```
   void UniverseManager::ApplySpeedVector()
   { 
   std::list <Star>::const_iterator iStar;

       for (iStar = mStars.begin(); iStar != mStars.end(); ++iStar)
       {
           // how to I get a hold on the object the iterator is pointing to so I can modify its values
                   // i tried  Star &star = *iStar;  this is illegal
                   // tried just using the iStar->mLocation += iStar->mSpeed this also fails due to the operator not accepting the values not sure why
                   // tried other things as well, so what is the proper way to do this?

           iStar->SetLocationData( iStar->mLocation += iStar->mSpeed);
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> ```
> std::list<Star>::const_iterator iStar;
> ```

You cannot modify the objects in a container via a `const_iterator`.  If you want to modify the objects, you need to use an `iterator` (i.e., `std::list<Star>::iterator`).

Comment: and then how do you go about it?  Can you use Star &star = *iStar;  or is there a better way?

Comment: Sure, you can use a reference to the element.  Or you can access the element through the iterator each time you need it.

Answer (score 3):

As James told you, you should use a `std::list<Star>::iterator` so that you can modify the object by calling a method or accessing its member variables.

It would be something like this:

```
void UniverseManager::ApplySpeedVector()
{
    std::list <Star>::iterator iStar;

    for (iStar = mStars.begin(); iStar != mStars.end(); ++iStar)
    {
        iStar->SetLocationData(iStar->mLocation += iStar->mSpeed);
    }
}
```

Nevertheless, if you want to improve your code you might prefer to have a getter for accessing the location and the speed:

```
void UniverseManager::ApplySpeedVector()
{
    std::list <Star>::iterator iStar;

    for (iStar = mStars.begin(); iStar != mStars.end(); ++iStar)
    {
        iStar->SetLocationData(iStar->GetLocationData() + iStar->GetSpeed());
    }
}
```

In any case, you have to use a non-const iterator.